# Recreating a Tree With Augmented Difficulty of Adding a Node Halfway Between Two Already Existing Nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, forest

This is a follow-up question to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/703321/recreating-a-tree-with-the-complication-of-placing-the-nodes-on-one-line), which [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr) kindly provided an answer to, and by cfr's recommendation which was produced in response to a comment of mine, I propose it in the format of a new question. The object is to recreate the below image

[image]

Now, I have searched the [Forest manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest-doc.pdf) on how to add a node halfway between two already existing nodes, and could not find a way. I tried to use the instructions of the Chapter 30 of TikZ manual, namely Graph Drawing Layouts: Trees, but sadly I cannot use `lualatex`, because I need to utilize `xepersian`. I tried to use `trees` library, but the output was vastly different and hideous. I am sorry if this question does not show effort or research. It was truly beyond me to figure it out. I appreciate your assistance in advance.

Comment: You could just add literally a node on the edges between level 2 and 3 instead of adding a level with different distances but that's possible with `forest` as well, I'm sure.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Could you kindly name where I should look in the `forest` manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [cfr's great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703351/47927) which you seem to refer to in your question and expanded it a bit more to make it possible to append another node between two levels:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703351/ i gwestiwn Arian: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/703321/
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    circle,
    fill=black,
    edge={{Latex[length=6pt,width=3pt]}-},
    grow'=north,
    calign=fixed edge angles,
    inner sep=0.5pt,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    for tree={
      my label/.option=content,
      content={.},
    }
  },
  additional/.style={
    edge path/.process={ O+nn= ? p w1 {level}{0} {_{below}} {On= ? {n}{1} {left}{right}} {
        \noexpand\path
            (!u.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor) 
            node[midway, circle, fill=black, inner sep=0.5pt, label={##1:$#1$}] (m) {.};
        \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
            (!u.parent anchor) -- (m); 
        \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
            (m) -- (.child anchor) 
            \forestoption{edge label};
        }
    }
  },
  my label/.style={
    label/.process={ O+nn= ? p w1 {level}{0} {_{below}} {On= ? {n}{1} {left}{right}} {##1:{$#1$}} },
  },
  [g 
    [e 
      [c,additional={c'}
        [a ]
        [b ]
      ]
      [d ]
    ]
    [f,additional={f'} ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Adding the numbers for the levels is probably done easiest manually. You can just place `\node`s inside the `forest` environment at the end. The *y* coordinate is equal to the level per default, so placing the nodes is fairly easy:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703351/ i gwestiwn Arian: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/703321/
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    circle,
    fill=black,
    edge={{Latex[length=6pt,width=3pt]}-},
    grow'=north,
    calign=fixed edge angles,
    inner sep=0.5pt,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    for tree={
      my label/.option=content,
      content={.},
    }
  },
  additional/.style={
    edge path/.process={ O+nn= ? p w1 {level}{0} {_{below}} {On= ? {n}{1} {left}{right}} {
        \noexpand\path
            (!u.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor) 
            node[midway, circle, fill=black, inner sep=0.5pt, label={##1:$#1$}] (m) {.};
        \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
            (!u.parent anchor) -- (m); 
        \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
            (m) -- (.child anchor) 
            \forestoption{edge label};
        }
    }
  },
  my label/.style={
    label/.process={ O+nn= ? p w1 {level}{0} {_{below}} {On= ? {n}{1} {left}{right}} {##1:{$#1$}} },
  },
  [g 
    [e 
      [c,additional={c'}
        [a ]
        [b ]
      ]
      [d ]
    ]
    [f,additional={f'} ]
  ]
  \foreach \l in {1,...,4} {
    \node at (2,{\l-1}) {$\l$};
  } 
  \node at (2,0.5) {$1\frac{1}{2}$};
  \node at (2,1.5) {$2\frac{1}{2}$};
  \node at (2,3.5) {Level};  
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An automated solution would be more tricky, especially considering the in-between nodes.

Comment: Excellent job. Could you please suggest a method or a place in the manual for placing the numbers as well? I know how to place the numbers with `calc` library of tikz, but with `'forest' I don't.

Comment: @Arian I added something to my answer. It is just plain Ti*k*Z added to the `forest` environment which is totally possible. I think this might be the easiest way.

Comment: I don't think this will work for the tree shown in the question because my answer can't be straightforwardly extended to produce that structure. There's a conflict between keeping the angles fixed and aligning the nodes on tiers. I think this can be fixed, but it doesn't work out-of-the-box. (@Arian)

Comment: @cfr Thanks for pointing this out. Well, at least the basic logic of replacing the edge to add another "in-between" node should work with other trees as well.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Absolutely. The `edge path'` can simplify things, but you have to juggle a bit in this case. And I only realised the issue while seeing how I'd answer this followup.

Comment: @cfr Your answer is great! I experienced similar problems with alignment and things. So, I won't extend my answer any further =)

Answer (score 3):

This answer both attempts to answer this new question and corrects [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703351/) to [the previous one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/703321/). While it is not obvious in [the original example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/703321/), attempting to extend [my earlier answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703351/) to draw the tree in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/703457/) demonstrates a problem.

Ignoring the halfway nodes and tier labels for now, the obvious way to extend the basic structure of the tree is

```
  [g 
    [e 
      [c, 
        [a ]
        [b_2 [, phantom][b_1]]
      ]
      [d_3, [, phantom][d_2 [, phantom][d_1]]]
    ]
    [f_5 [, phantom][f_4,  [, phantom][f_3 [, phantom][f_2 [, phantom][f_1]]]] ]
  ]
```

Compiling this with the preamble from my previous answer, we see the problem:

[image: illustration of problem]

We would like the following sets of nodes to be horizontally aligned:

- b1 -- d1 -- f2
- a -- b2 -- d2 -- f3
- c -- b3 -- d3 -- f4
- d -- f5

However, only the last pair are horizontally aligned. In the first three sets of nodes, the f node is lower than its tier-mates.

This is because `forest` is trying to both align the nodes on tiers and ensure `fixed edge angles` for straight lines. It does one, but in doing the other, it partially undoes the first. Removing either option takes us further from the desired result.

Basically, there is a conflict between aligning nodes to tiers and using `fixed edge angles`. It's possible to fix this, but I'm not aware of an out-of-the-box solution, so it is a bit more complex.

This probably doesn't deal with all the corner cases, but it should work better for a greater number of edge (and node!) trees.

```
\begin{forest}
  aligned tree,
  label tiers,
  [g 
    [e 
      [c, double here
        [a ]
        [b_2 [, phantom][b_1]]
      ]
      [d_3, double here [, phantom][d_2 [, phantom][d_1]]]
    ]
    [f_5 [, phantom][f_4, double here [, phantom][f_3 [, phantom][f_2 [, phantom][f_1]]]] ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: additional half-levels and correction for conflicting fixed edge angles and tier alignment]

`aligned tree` is a modified version of the code posted in my earlier answer, turned into a style for convenience. The current version `declare`s custom `forest` options and this doesn't always work inside the `forest` environment, so I find it easier to set everything up beforehand.

`label tiers` labels the levels and, if applicable half-levels. The format is determined by the style definitions, which can obviously be tweaked as desired.

`double here` causes an additional node to be inserted. This node is not part of the structure of the tree. It is rather just constructed as part of drawing the edge from the parent. It is thus very similar to the approach in [Jasper Habicht's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703462/).

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
% atebion: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703530/ a https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703351/ i gwestiwn Arian: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/703321/
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\forestset{%
  declare toks={double content}{},
  declare boolean={doubled level}{0},
  my label/.style={%
    label/.process={ O+nn= ? p w1 {level}{0} {_{below}} {On= ? {n}{1} {left}{right}} {##1:{$#1$}} },
  },
  my double label/.style 2 args={%
    edge path'={%
      (!u.parent anchor) edge node (a) [pos=1,inner sep=.5pt,circle,fill,label=#2:{$#1$}] {.} ($(!u.parent anchor)!.5!(.child anchor)$) (a) -- (.child anchor) 
    },
  },
  aligned tree/.style={%
    for tree={
      circle,
      fill=black,
      edge={{Latex[length=6pt,width=3pt]}-},
      grow'=north,
      calign=fixed angles,
      inner sep=0.5pt,
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      for tree={%
        my label/.option=content,
        content={.},
        tier/.process={Ow+n{level}{##1+1}},
      },
    },
    align to tier,
  },
  double here/.style={%
    content+={'},
    double content/.option=content,
    double content+={'},
    before typesetting nodes={%
      my double label/.process={ O  Od< ?  {double content}  {x}{0pt} {left}{right} },
      tempcountb/.option=level,
      sort by={>O+n{id}},
      for nodewalk={%
        filter={root',descendants}{>O+nR={level}{tempcountb}},
      }{doubled level},
    },
  },
  align to tier/.style={%
    before computing xy={%
      tempdima/.max={l}{tree},
      tempdimb/.max={s}{tree},
      for descendants={%
        l/.register=tempdima,
        if={>Od>{s}{0pt}}{s/.register=tempdimb}{s=-\foresteregister{tempdimb}},
      },
    },
  },
  label tiers/.style={%
    before drawing tree={%
      tempcounta/.max={level}{tree},
      tikz+={\node  [level label,anchor=south west] (x) at ([xshift=15pt,yshift=5pt]current bounding box.north east) {Levels};},
      for nodewalk={%
        do until={>OR={level}{tempcounta}}{fake=next leaf},
        do until={>O!{phantom}}{fake=next on tier},
        current and ancestors
      }{%
        tikz+/.process={Ow{tier}{\node (tier label ##1) [level label] at (.center -| x.center) {$##1$};}},
        if={>O{doubled level}}{%
          tikz+/.process={Ow{level}{%
              \path (!u.center -| x.center) -- (.center -| x.center) node [level label,midway] {$##1\frac{1}{2}$} ;
            }%
          }
        }{},
      },
    },
  },
  /tikz/level label/.style={anchor=center,font=\sffamily},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  aligned tree,
  label tiers,
  [g 
    [e 
      [c, double here
        [a ]
        [b_2 [, phantom][b_1]]
      ]
      [d_3, double here [, phantom][d_2 [, phantom][d_1]]]
    ]
    [f_5 [, phantom][f_4, double here [, phantom][f_3 [, phantom][f_2 [, phantom][f_1]]]] ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```