# Recreating a Forest with Different Angles and Parallel Lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, istgame

I have utilized the code which [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr) has beautifully generated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/703321/recreating-a-tree-with-the-complication-of-placing-the-nodes-on-one-line) to recreate the below image:
[image]
A MWE of my efforts is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={
            circle,
            fill=black,
            calign=fixed edge angles,
            inner sep=0.5pt,
        },
        before typesetting nodes={
            for tree={%
                my label/.option=content,
                content={.},
            }
        },
        my label/.style={%
            label/.process={ O+nn= ? p w1 {level}{0} {_{below}} {On= ? {n}{1} {left}{right}} {##1:{$#1$}} },
            %   if level=0{label=below:{$#1$}}{if n=1{label=left:{$#1$}}{label=right:{$#1$}}},
        },
        [ 
        [,edge label={node(y1)[midway,left,font=\scriptsize]{1}}
        [7,name=chap,edge label={node(y2)[midway,left,font=\scriptsize]{1}}
        [,phantom]
        [6,edge label={node [midway,right,font=\scriptsize]{0}}
        [,phantom]
        [5,edge label={node [midway,right,font=\scriptsize]{0}}]
        ]
        ]
        [6,edge label={node [midway,right,font=\scriptsize]{0}}
        [,phantom]
        [,edge label={node [midway,right,font=\scriptsize]{0}}
        [5,edge label={node [midway,left,font=\scriptsize]{1}}]
        [,phantom]
        ]
        ]
        ]
        [,edge label={node[midway,right,font=\scriptsize]{0}}
        [,edge label={node[midway,left,font=\scriptsize]{1}}]
        [,edge label={node[midway,right,font=\scriptsize]{0}}
        [,name=y4,edge label={node(y3)[midway,left,font=\scriptsize]{1}}]
        [,phantom]
        ]
        ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following image:
[image]

Which as you can observe, apart from being incomplete (which is due to the fact that I cannot draw the rest of the graph, for want of space) has two issues with it:

- The labels "6" and "5" are in the wrong place.
- The angle between the edges is too acute.

Could you please assist me with the defined style so that the resultant graph resembles the desired one already shown above?

Comment: The first thing my answer there says is to please not use that code, but https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703530/ instead. That won't necessarily solve your particular problem, but it should avoid at least some problems in many cases. Could you clarify whether you need both straight lines and tier alignment? The combination is what makes these tricky so, if you don't need both, it's easier to avoid my code altogether. If you do need both, that's a different thing. Note that my later answer makes using the code a bit easier, too, as it provides styles.

Comment: The tier alignment is crucial, because every number with the same y-coordinate belongs to the same level. Also, the straight lines need to be parallel.

Comment: That isn't possible. You can do what Sandy G does - which seems to be what's shown in your target image - but the straight lines are not then parallel. They can't be parallel without nodes overlapping. The reason it works in the earlier diagram is that it just happens that all the overlaps involve at most one non-phantom. That's not true in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by setting `calign=fixed edge angles`, and then specifying the angles for each pair of children (the angles are taken with 0 vertical, negative to the left, positive to the right. You must add some `phantom` children to make this work. Note that `calign angle=θ` is an abbreviation for: `calign primary angle=-θ, calign secondary angle=θ`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\tikzset{dot/.style={fill, circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=5pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={dot, calign=fixed edge angles, l sep=1cm}
[, calign angle=60
    [, calign primary angle=-60, calign secondary angle=30
        [, label=left:7, calign angle=30
            [, phantom][, label=left:6, calign angle=30[, phantom][, label=left:5]]
        ]
        [, label=left:6, calign angle=30
            [, phantom][, calign angle=30[, phantom][, label=left:5]]
        ]
    ]
    [, calign primary angle=-30, calign secondary angle=60
        [, label=left:6
            [, phantom][, calign angle=30, label=below:$5\le\mathit{PROF}$]
        ]
        [, calign primary angle=-30, calign secondary angle=60
            [, label=left:6, calign angle=30[, phantom][, label=left:6]]
            [, calign angle=30[][, phantom]]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following gets you a more-or-less automatic layout at the cost of a *lot* of space. It makes for a very long-legged tree. `phantom`s still need to be inserted for shaping purposes, but are added automatically to counteract the conflict between aligning on tiers and `calign=fixed angles`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/711690/ addaswyd o/i gwestiwn Arian: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/711587/
% atebion: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703530/ a https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703351/ i gwestiwn Arian: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/703321/
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\forestset{%
  my label/.style={%
    label/.process={ O+nn= ? p w1 {n children}{0} {_{below}} {On= ? {n}{1} {left}{right}} {##1:{$#1$}} },
  },
  align tree B/.style={%
    for tree={
      circle,
      fill=black,
      calign=fixed angles,
      inner sep=0.5pt,
      tier/.option=level,
    },
    delay={
      where phantom={}{%
        my label/.option=content,
        content={.},
      },
    },
    spread align to tier,
  },
  my phantom/.style={%
    phantom,
    tier/.option=level,
  },
  spread align to tier/.style={%
    before typesetting nodes={%
      tempcounta/.max={level}{tree},
      not tempboola,
      until={>R{tempboola}}{%
        tempboola,
        for tree breadth-first={%
          if={ > OR< On= & {level}{tempcounta} {n children}{0} }{%
            repeat=2{append={[,my phantom]}},
            not tempboola,
          }{},
        },
        do dynamics,
      },
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  align tree B,
  for tree={%
    math content,
    calign angle=50,
  },
  where n=1{%
    edge label={node [midway,left,font=\scriptsize]{1}},
  }{
    edge label={node [midway,right,font=\scriptsize]{0}},
  },
  [ 
    [
      [7
        [,phantom]
        [6
          [,phantom]
          [5]
        ]
      ]
      [6
        [,phantom]
        [
          [5]
          [,phantom]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [
      [
        [,phantom]
        [5\leq\textsc{prof}]
      ]
      [
        [6
          [,phantom]
          [6]
        ]
        [, phantom
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: leggy tree]

Forest's layout algorithm doesn't handle this kind of tree with the grace or elegance one might ideally prefer!